# Sort pkg.go.dev imported-by view

Tags: go

I would like to sort the "imported-by view" (example of [wire](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/wire?tab=importedby)) by "most often imported".

For example "bitbucket.org/toggleglobal/germ" is only imported by 1.

[image: go-wire-imported-by]

But I like to see which package has the most imported-by count.

Source: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/wire?tab=importedby

Comment: I asked this very question on Gophers Slack [a while back](https://gophers.slack.com/archives/C029RQSEE/p1649274676451919). Apparently, pkg.go.dev doesn't provide this functionality. However, someone pointed me to https://libs.garden/go.